# How can i handle sqlite3 error correctly?

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I have problem with sqlite3 error. How can i handle the error "SQLITE_CANTOPEN"?

```
var db = new sqlite3.Database('./db/db_main.db', sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return console.error(err.message);
    }

    else if (err.error == "SQLITE_CANTOPEN") {
        let dbFile = fs.readFileSync("./db/db_main.db");

        fs.writeFile(dbFile, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;

            console.log("The Database was successfully created!");
        })
    }

    console.log('Connected to the main SQlite database.');
});
```

```
{ [Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file] errno: 14, code: 'SQLITE_CANTOPEN' }
```

Comment: The *else if* will never be reached because it will enter the previous *if*.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the `if` statements.

```
if(err) {
    // An error exists
} else if(err.error === 'SQLITE_CANTOPEN') {
    // This code will never be executed.
    // What you checked here is whether the err **NOT** exists and err.error is your specific error
}
```

Instead you can change the `if` statement to

```
if (err && err.error === 'SQLITE_CANTOPEN') {
    // Handle your error here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem another way.
I did so:

```
var db = new sqlite3.Database('./db/db_main.db', sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE | sqlite3.OPEN_CREATE, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err.message);
    }

    db.run('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hashes` (hash VARCHAR)');

    console.log('Connected to the main SQlite database.');
});
```

Add `sqlite3.OPEN_CREATE`, remove unnecessary.